# FindStr to search sql scripts for multiple Regexes

Tags: regex, findstr

Have two sets of Generated Scripts from SQL replicated reporting databases for two different versions of an Application.

The old application had 2300+ unnecessary tables (supported the vendor's other products), which are not present in the new version.

I need to recreate functions, stored queries and views (maybe other stuff too) in the new database. I have the definitions in the Generate Scripts output as individual .sql files. The problem is that many of the files contain references to the missing tables, so I want to do a kind of dependency analysis to get the list of things I can't create because they refer to Tables (and later views) that don't exist.

I have a list of missing tables in a file, I want to use that as a list of things to search.

I need a regex which looks for lines which start with "FROM " (and later INNER JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN) and is followed by one of the missing table names (there may be other text on the line too, like aliases.) I've used Notepad++ to force all occurrences of |FROM|INNER JOIN|LEFT INNER JOIN| to be at the start of a new line.

I tried using findstr with the /g parameter so that I could have a file full of regex patterns, but it doesn't seem to match correctly.

eg `findstr /i /r /g:mt.txt *.sql`

mt.txt sample

```
^FROM\ action.*
^FROM\ actiongroup.*
^FROM\ actiontype.*
```

I think my issue is related to the space after the word FROM, when I try to use the /c parameter of findstr it always says it is ignored.

I'm also open to using grep or perl to solve this if possible
Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: `findstr /i /r /g:mt.txt *.sql` with `mt.txt` with provided lines works fine. The space must not be escaped with a backslash, but escaping the space is no mistake. The mistake was most likely saving file `mt.txt` not as ASCII/ANSI file, but as Unicode file with UTF-16 encoding.